# Editar diretamente via FTP com Sublime Text

Tags: ftp, sublime-text-2

Quero trabalhar via FTP com o Sublime Text 2. Não quero apenas conectar via FTP e transferir arquivos, mas sim, editar o arquivo, e quando salvá-lo, ele envia diretamente para o servidor, por FTP. Assim, como é feito no Komodo. Isso é possível?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essa funcionalidade não está disponível no *core* do Sublime Text, mas é possível com plugins. Uma pesquisa no Google encontrou dois entre os primeiros resultados:

- **[SublimeText2-FTPSync](https://github.com/NoxArt/SublimeText2-FTPSync)**
  Gratuito, mas sem suporte a SFTP
- **[Sublime SFTP](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp)**
  Pago (USD 20), com suporte a SFTP

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta leiga. Mas, é necessário SFTP? O FTPSync exige a instalação do SFTP?

Comment: @FelipeStoker Eu na verdade nunca usei esses plugins. Mas se você não precisa de SFTP (que é como o FTP, mas por SSH), a primeira opção deve servir.

Answer (score 5):

Cara, eu costumo usar o [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) como Client para FTP, e tenho configurado o Sublime como editor padrão para ele...e quando faço edição a partir dos arquivos do servidor, salvando o FileZilla já pergunta se quero enviar ao servidor novamente com as alterações.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de salvar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso funciona para editar um arquivo individual, mas se quiser trabalhar com um projeto, não serve (por exemplo, não dá para abrir um arquivo com CTRL+T).

Comment: Obrigado amigo. Mas, eu gostaria de editar direto no servidor, pelo que vi não é tão simples quanto parece, bem que poderia ser igual ao Komodo, apenas instalar um plugin e ponto final.

Comment: Esse esquema é bom, mas somente para edições pontuais. Mas acho válida a resposta como uma alternativa para casos específicos.

Answer (score 2):

Se você ainda procura por isso, tanto no SFTP quanto no FTPSync, pode-se fazer alterando a linha " 'upload_on_save': false " para " 'upload_on_save': true" no arquivo de configurações do próprio plugin, onde você fornece o host, user e pass. Desta forma ao salvar o arquivo o plugin faz o upload automaticamente. Vlw Flw

Answer (score 0):

Já tentei fazer isso também, na qual vida de programador, isso mesmo desafios todos os dias, um programa leve que faz isso é o cute ftp.

Comment: Essa resposta está um tanto incompleta quanto estranha (como se fosse traduzida para português por um tradutor online).